# Why isnt pageSize parameter offered for IStatement prototype of ISession.Execute

Tags: c#, cassandra, execute, datastax

I see that we can call:

```
      public RowSet ExecuteRowSet(string statement, int? pageSize = null)
    {
        return pageSize.HasValue ? _session.Execute(statement, pageSize.Value) : _session.Execute(statement);
    }
```

but we cannot call:

```
      public RowSet ExecuteRowSet(BoundStatement statement, int? pageSize = null)
    {
        return pageSize.HasValue ? _session.Execute(statement, pageSize.Value) : _session.Execute(statement);
    }
```

Why is pageSize not provided for a BoundStatement?

Comment: You're using the DataStax C# driver?

Comment: Yes, sorry I neglected that fact.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a page size, you can use the SetPageSize method on the statement class.  So for a bound statement, this might look like:

```cs
boundStatement = boundStatement.SetPageSize(100);
RowSet rows = session.Execute(boundStatement);

// Now iterate over the RowSet and subsequent pages will be loaded transparently as needed by the enumerator
foreach(Row row in rows)
{
   // Do something
}
```

Note: this is to take advantage of the [automatic paging feature](http://www.slideshare.net/LukeTillman/a-deep-dive-into-apache-cassandra-for-net-developers/65) in the driver and not for manual paging scenarios like showing a paging UI in an application.  The other overload you mention is just a shortcut/convenience method for quickly executing CQL and optionally using automatic paging.  It's basically equivalent to doing:

```cs
var simpleStatement = new SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM sometable");
simpleStatement.SetPageSize(100);
RowSet rows = session.Execute(simpleStatement);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It does.  But if the actual result set is 1000K rows and we page with 100 rows, does each call to 'Do Something' force the rowset to maintain a pointer or cursor (not sure of the terminology in Cassandra) to be maintained?  I am trying to understand the overhead ( I understand the benefit and just want to know the limits to the benefit)

Comment: Under the covers, the RowSet will make subsequent calls when the current page of records is exhausted.  The overhead is just a "token" (I think it's actually exposed as the PageState property) that gets sent to Cassandra on requests for the next page so that Cassandra knows which record to start at for the next page.  Keep in mind that because that call to get the next page happens as part of the iterator (i.e. the foreach part of the example) you could get an Exception thrown from that block if there's a problem retrieving subsequent pages.